# Flutter Firebase Push Notification unable to data if app is not launched

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Flutter for my code. For push notification, I am using Firebase Push Notification ("firebase_messaging" version 9.1.3).

I am facing the following issue:

- I am able to receive Push Notification for both Android and iOS from the server.
- If I have launched the app and then put the app in the background, when I click the notification message from the home screen, my app will launch (from background) and I am able to extract the payload data.
- If I have not launched the app, when I click the notification message from the Home Screen, my app will load but I am not able to extract the payload data.

Below is my code that listen to the message (referencing from Flutter example).

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  //Process received message 
  _processMessage(message);
});
```

What am I missing to enable the app to receive the notification payload if it launched fresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember, `onMessageOpenedApp` is only triggered when the app is launched from the background state.

For receiving notification payload when launching from the terminated state, you have to use `getInitialMessage()` method.

More on that can be found [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/notifications#handling-interaction).

Comment: I just checked this and it works. Thanks for pointing this out.